# Changing movie genre in AppleTV (4th Generation)?

Tags: itunes, appletv

- Apple TV (4th Gen)
- MBP (15" w/ TB)

I have a few hundred movies purchased through iTunes, some have mismatched genres, some I'd like to create my own.

Examples:

- Rush Hour 1 & 3 are marked as Comedy
- Rush Hour 2 is marked as Action & Adventure
- Grouping all James Bond movies under a genre of the same name

I found [this article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1137856/appletvfolders.html) from 2009 that explains how to do this with AppleTV out at the time.

On my MBP:iTunes, I can CMD+Select multiple movies > Get Info > Change Genre. This is reflected in iTunes on my MBP, the article then states

> Now re-sync your Apple TV (in the Devices section of iTunes, select the Apple TV and click Sync) and you’re done.

On my MBP:iTunes, there is nothing listed under Devices.

Do I need to turn on Home Sharing to have the genres updated on the Apple TV or does the device no longer "sync" local genre changes vs. iTunes defaults?

Follow up question: If this can be done, is there a way to specify sort preferences per genre (e.g. list Bond genre movies by year)?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the genres in iTunes.  On the ATV, access the movies through Home Sharing, NOT through the Movies app.  Using the Movies app will show you movies you've purchased, but with all of the original data from Apple.  Using Home Sharing (the "Computers" app), you'll see the movies and genres stored on your local computer.

There hasn't been sync'ing since ATV1, I think...